# Resolve promise on external event

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I want to resolve a promise when an event happens in a different function

```
const trigger = function() {}

const eventHandler = async function() {
  while(true) {
    await new Promise (resolve => {
      
    }
    // Code when the promise fulfills.
  }
}

const cleaner = function() {
  trigger()
}

cleaner()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that really easily by re-assigning the `trigger`:

```
let trigger = () => {}

const eventHandler = async function() {
  while(true) {
    await new Promise (resolve => {
      trigger = resolve
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    // Code when the promise fulfills.
  }
}

const cleaner = function() {
  trigger() // calls resolve to fulfill the currently waited-for promise
}

eventHandler() // start waiting
cleaner()
```

However, notice that this is generally regarded as a bad practice, you should start whatever leads to the external event, and especially installing the event listener, *inside* the `new Promise` executor callback, where you trivially have access to the `resolve` function.

Answer (score -1):

Below is an example of how you might go about making a promise cancelable. We're using a helper function makeCancelable() that takes a promise, and returns a different promise and a cancel function. There's no way to just "cancel" an existing promise, especially when you don't have control over how the promise is made, but what you can do it wrap the existing promise in a new one that's behaves just like the original, but is also ready to resolve on command.

```js
// Helper function that just waits for a timeout
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

function makeCancelable(promise) {
  let resolveWrappedPromise
  return {
    promise: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolveWrappedPromise = resolve
      promise.then(resolve, reject)
    }),
    cancel: value => resolveWrappedPromise(value),
  }
}

cancelPromise = () => {} // function used by onClick event
async function eventHandler() {
  while (true) {
    const { promise, cancel } = makeCancelable(wait(1000).then(() => 'Success!'))
    cancelPromise = cancel
    console.log(await promise)
  }
}

eventHandler()
```

```html
<button onclick="cancelPromise('Canceled!')">Cancel!</button>
```

In this code example, "Success!" will print out every second - unless you push the button to cancel the current promise. Repeated pushes of the button will delay "Success!" from being printed indefinably, because the promise was canceled and provided with the value "Canceled!" when cancellation occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [waitFor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter2#emitterwaitforevent--eventns-options) method of the EventEmitter2 package ([Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-fermat-3ryrm?file=/src/index.js)).

```
import EventEmitter2 from "eventemitter2";

const emitter = new EventEmitter2();

(async () => {
  const data = await emitter.waitFor("test");
  console.log("emitted", data);
})();

setTimeout(() => emitter.emit("test", 1, 2, 3), 1000);
```